# Translate SQL Query to JPQL - @ManyToMany join

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I'm trying to translate SQL native query usage in @Query("...", native=true) Spring Data Jpa annotation, to JPQL query usage within the same annotation.
SQL Query:

```
select d.id as doctorId, d.firstName as doctorFirstName, d.lastName as doctorLastName, d.title as doctorTitle, 
d.email as doctorEmail, v.id as id, v.dateFrom as dateFrom, v.dateTo as dateTo, v.status as status,
md.id as medicalServicesId, md.service as medicalServicesService, md.price as medicalServicesPrice 
from Visit v 
left outer join Doctor d on v.doctor_id=d.id 
left outer join visit_medical_services vms on v.id=vms.medical_services_id 
left outer join MedicalService md on vms.visit_id=md.id 
where d.id= :doctorId and v.status= :status and v.dateFrom>= :dateFrom and v.dateTo<= :dateTo
```

I'm using Spring Projected Interface, that's why columns aliases are named liked this.

Now i want to get exactly the same result with JPQL - list of items. What i did tried it's this:

```
    @Query("select d.id as doctorId, d.firstName as doctorFirstName, d.lastName as doctorLastName, d.title as doctorTitle, d.email as doctorEmail, " +
            "v.id as id, v.dateFrom as dateFrom, v.dateTo as dateTo, v.status as status, md.id as medicalServicesId, md.service as medicalServicesService, md.price as medicalServicesPrice \n" +
            "from Visit v \n" +
            "left outer join Doctor d on v.doctor.id=d.id \n" +
            "left outer join v.medicalServices vms on vms.id=v.id \n" +
            "left outer join MedicalService md on md.id=vms.id \n" +
            "where d.id= :doctorId and v.status= :status and v.dateFrom>= :dateFrom and v.dateTo<= :dateTo")
    List<VisitInfoWithPatientAndMedServices3joins> getAllVisitInfoWithPatientAndMedicalServicesJpqlQuery
    (@Param("doctorId") Long doctorId, @Param("status") VisitStatus status, @Param("dateFrom") LocalDateTime dateFrom, @Param("dateTo") LocalDateTime dateTo, Pageable pageable);
```

And here is translated SQL from JPQL.

```
select doctor1_.id as col_0_0_, doctor1_.firstName as col_1_0_, doctor1_.lastName as col_2_0_, doctor1_.title as col_3_0_, doctor1_.email as col_4_0_, visit0_.id as col_5_0_, visit0_.dateFrom as col_6_0_, visit0_.dateTo as col_7_0_, visit0_.status as col_8_0_, medicalser4_.id as col_9_0_, medicalser4_.service as col_10_0_, medicalser4_.price as col_11_0_ 
from Visit visit0_ 
left outer join  
(visit_medical_services medicalser2_ left outer join MedicalService medicalser3_ on medicalser2_.visit_id=medicalser3_.id) on visit0_.id=medicalser2_.medical_services_id 
and (medicalser3_.id=visit0_.id) 
left outer join Doctor doctor1_ on (visit0_.doctor_id=doctor1_.id) 
left outer join MedicalService medicalser4_ on (medicalser4_.id=medicalser3_.id) where doctor1_.id=? and visit0_.status=? and visit0_.dateFrom>=? and visit0_.dateTo<=? limit ?
```

And the problem here is, that it's returning columns from @ManyToMany relations (visit_medical_services) but ONLY FOR THE FIRST OBJECT. Json response from Postman below:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "status": "PAID",
        "dateFrom": "2019-04-10T08:00:00",
        "dateTo": "2019-04-10T08:30:00",
        "medicalServicesId": 1,
        "medicalServicesService": "Visit",
        "medicalServicesPrice": 100.0,
        "doctorLastName": "James",
        "doctorFirstName": "Alex",
        "doctorEmail": "james@gmail.com",
        "doctorId": 1,
        "doctorTitle": "dr n. md."
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "status": "PAID",
        "dateFrom": "2019-04-10T09:00:00",
        "dateTo": "2019-04-10T09:30:00",
        "medicalServicesId": null,
        "medicalServicesService": null,
        "medicalServicesPrice": null,
        "doctorLastName": "James",
        "doctorFirstName": "Alex",
        "doctorEmail": "james@gmail.com",
        "doctorId": 1,
        "doctorTitle": "dr n. md."
    }
]
```

I tried to use translated SQL query using JPQL in Workbench, because I'm using MySQL database and the result is the same - first object is correct, and the rest have null values inside mapped @ManyToMany colums.
Here are my Entity classes if it would this issue a little bit easier:

```
public class Visit {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;
    LocalDateTime dateFrom;
    LocalDateTime dateTo;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    VisitStatus status;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "doctor_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = true)
    @JsonManagedReference
    Doctor doctor;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonManagedReference
    @JoinColumn(name = "patient_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = true)
    Patient patient;
    @ManyToMany
    @JsonManagedReference
    @JoinTable(
            name = "visit_diseases",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "disease_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "visit_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    List<Disease> diseases;
    @ManyToMany
    @JsonManagedReference
    @JoinTable(
            name = "visit_medical_services",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "medical_services_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "visit_id"))
    Set<MedicalService> medicalServices;
    String mainSymptoms;
    String treatment;
    String allergy;
    String addiction;
    String comment;
}
```

And Medical Services:

```
public class MedicalService {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    Long id;
    String service;
    Float price;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "medicalServices", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Visit> visits;

    public MedicalService(Long id, String service, float price) {
        this.id = id;
        this.service = service;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

Can someone take a look please and explain to me what is not working correctly here? What i want to achive is to make JPQL generate **THE SAME** SQL query. It is even possible? Please help me...

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the equivalent sql query for your jpql gtting generated in console by turning show-sql on?

Comment: Sure, I just edited question and below JPQL @Query you can see generated SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few errors in your query. Use the following instead

```
@Query("select d.id as doctorId, d.firstName as doctorFirstName, d.lastName as doctorLastName, d.title as doctorTitle, d.email as doctorEmail, " +
        "v.id as id, v.dateFrom as dateFrom, v.dateTo as dateTo, v.status as status, md.id as medicalServicesId, md.service as medicalServicesService, md.price as medicalServicesPrice \n" +
        "from Visit v \n" +
        "left outer join v.doctor d \n" +
        "left outer join v.medicalServices md \n"
        "where d.id= :doctorId and v.status= :status and v.dateFrom>= :dateFrom and v.dateTo<= :dateTo")
List<VisitInfoWithPatientAndMedServices3joins> getAllVisitInfoWithPatientAndMedicalServicesJpqlQuery
(@Param("doctorId") Long doctorId, @Param("status") VisitStatus status, @Param("dateFrom") LocalDateTime dateFrom, @Param("dateTo") LocalDateTime dateTo, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: "The on part might be unnecessary" - indeed. Without this part it's working perfect, with it it's not working. Please edit your answer and i will mark it as solution. Btw, thanks a lot!